# UI elements are not detected after renaming .aspx file and the class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I was working on a project in ASP.NET and I needed to rename the .aspx file. So I did that and noticed that the class name hasn't changed. I did the standard Ctrl+R twice trick and got a message saying that it hasn't been renamed everywhere. Ctrl+Z didn't help and trying to rename it back to what it was also didn't help. Now throughout the whole file Visual Studio complains that elements such as Tables and TextBoxes don't exist. Is there a way to fix this without making a new project from scratch and migrating all the files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ctrl+Shift+H over the entire project (or solution, if need be) to rename your *old-class-name* to *new-class-name*. This will allow you to rename what has not been renamed without having to recreate your project from scratch. I suggest that you review each rename one-by-one (which the Ctrl-Shift-H function allows you to do) rather than blindly renaming everything without review.